# Reconize an Array method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Can you help me on something where I can't seem to get my code right.

It contains two flaws. I can't get it to read the Array so it compares the input.
And it doesn't add a number when it is reconized.

```
public class Bird {

    private ArrayList<Vogels> Name;
    private final Scanner scanner;
    private int observed;
    private String R;


    public Bird (Scanner scanner) {
        Name = new ArrayList<Vogels>();
        this.scanner = scanner;
        this.observed = 0;
        this.R = "";
    }
```

*The following method I can't seem to get it to work. I know the problem is somewhere in reading the Array, but I can't seem to get it to read it correctly.*

```
public void Obs(){
        System.out.print("What was Observed:?");
        R = scanner.nextLine();
        if (!Name.equals(R)){
            System.out.println("Is not a bird!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("added");
            this.observed++;
        }       
}
```

Comment: Your problem statements are pretty vague. Can you be more specific? Are you getting any errors? *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: do you always see "Is not a bird!"? Your `Name` field is a list, and `R` is a string. when you compare them it would always be false.

Comment: Something might wrong here ? `if (!Name.equals(R)){` Are you comparing `ArrayList` with `String`?

Answer (score 1):

**Name** is an `ArrayList` of **Vogels** and **R** is a `String`..

so this here  `if (!Name.equals(R)){` makes not much sense, and will return always false

you need or should implement/define something like `if(Name.contains(Vogels.resolve(R)))`
where `Vogels.resolve(R)` is a static method that returns a `Vogel` when you give as parameter a `String`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a string with array

```
if (!Name.equals(R)){
```

you have to get the object out of array first and get the value of the string from an object and then you have to compare.
Name.get(0) -> which gives an object Vogels(you have to write a logic either for loop or some other mechanism). You have to get an value out of object and then compare with string. Better post your Vogels object.

Comment: Siya ram chandra ki Jai !

Answer (score 0):

After looking into your codes, it looks like you want to check whether list contain the data read from file or not. If this is what you want, you can update your code as below:

```
 public void Obs(){
            System.out.print("What was Observed:?");
//Improve your reading from scanner
            R = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!Name.contains(Vogels.getVogels(R))){
                System.out.println("Is not a bird!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("added");
                this.observed++;
            }       
    }
```

Where getVogel is a method which will return Vogels based on the user provided string.

Comment: Name is an array list of type Vogels.java and hence checking if it contains String object referenced by R is not meaningful. You can check ΦXoce 웃 Пepeúpa answer, it makes more sense.